# Tab Bar Controller isHidden, but stays hidden

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, tabbar

Im currently designing an app that utilizes a tab bar controller.
On the messages tab (instant messages), I want the tab bar to disappear whenever a user is having/viewing his/her conversation with another person. To do so I used this:`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`
It disables the tabBar, but now the issue is that whenever I hit the back button to return to previous views (embedded in a navigation controller), the tab bar is still hidden. On the other views, I've set `tabBar.isHidden = false`, but that doesn't seem to fix it and now I can't access any of the other tabs.
My question is: How can I hide the tabBar on one view but keep it visible when I return to previous views?

Comment: just set `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false` before you return to previous views. That is, put it in `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TabBar firstViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Enable TabBar
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
}
```

In SecondViewController (Pushed from firstViewController)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Disable TabBar
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
}
```